# Can't Sign Up With My React Native App - Something Wrong With My API (maybe?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I'm trying to build a react native app and I can't seem to sign in. When I try I get a

> 'Signup Error - Something Went Wrong" general message.

I don't think my API is working and when I try it on postman I get a

> 404 message.

The URL should be fine so I'm not sure if it has something to do with a setting in the API backend or perhaps I'm botching my parameters somehow.

Here is my api.js code:

```
//const BASE_URL = "http://{ip address}:5000";
const BASE_URL = 'https://neighbor-hood.herokuapp.com';

export const api = async (url, method, body = null, headers = {}) => {

try {
  const endPoint = BASE_URL.concat(url);
  const reqBody = body ? JSON.stringify(body) : null;


  const fetchParams = {method, headers};

  if((method === "POST" || method === "PUT") && !reqBody) {
      throw new Error("Request body required");
  }
  if(reqBody) {
      fetchParams.headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
      fetchParams.body = reqBody;
  }
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(endPoint, fetchParams);

  let text = ''
  try{
    console.log("fetchResponse ", fetchResponse)
    text = await fetchResponse.text()
  } catch (err){
    console.log("Exception in turning text from response err", err)
  }

  return fetchResponse;
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Exception ", e)
  return e;
}
}
```

Here is my actions.js file that imports the api:

```
import {api} from "../service/api";

export const createNewUser = (payload) => {
return async (dispatch) => {

    try {
      dispatch({
        type: "CREATE_USER_LOADING"
      });

      const response = await api("/user/create", "POST", payload); 

      if(response.success) {
        dispatch({
            type: "CREAT_USER_SUCCESS"
        });
        dispatch({
            type: "AUTH_USER_SUCCESS",
            token: response.token
        });
        dispatch({
            type: "GET_USER_SUCCESS",
            payload: response.responseBody
        });

        return response;
      } else {
        throw response;
      }

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: "CREAT_USER_FAIL",
            payload: error.responseBody
        });
        return error;
    }
  }
}

export const loginUser = (payload) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {

    try {
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGIN_USER_LOADING"
      });

      const response = await api("/user/login", "POST", payload);

      if(response.success) {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS",
        });
        dispatch({
            type: "AUTH_USER_SUCCESS",
            token: response.token
        });
        dispatch({
            type: "GET_USER_SUCCESS",
            payload: response.responseBody
        });
        return response;
      } else {
        throw response;
      }

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN_USER_FAIL",
            payload: error.responseBody
        });
        return error;
    }
  }
}

export const logoutUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    try {
        const {authReducer: {authData: {token}}} = state;
        console.log(token);

        const response = await api("/user/logout", "DELETE", payload);
        console.log(response);
        dispatch({
            type: "USER_LOGGED_OUT_SUCCESS"
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I get back in the console:

```
fetchResponse  Response {
"_bodyBlob": Blob {
"_data": Object {
  "blobId": "DC45F3C7-FB3E-4120-8B92-0AC798181824",
  "name": "create.html",
  "offset": 0,
  "size": 232,
  "type": "text/html",
  },
  },
  "_bodyInit": Blob {
  "_data": Object {
  "blobId": "DC45F3C7-FB3E-4120-8B92-0AC798181824",
  "name": "create.html",
  "offset": 0,
  "size": 232,
  "type": "text/html",
  },
  },
  "headers": Headers {
  "map": Object {
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "232",
  "content-type": "text/html",
  "date": "Thu, 03 Oct 2019 18:15:10 GMT",
  "server": "gunicorn/19.9.0",
  "via": "1.1 vegur",
  },
  },
 "ok": false,
 "status": 404,
 "statusText": undefined,
 "type": "default",
 "url": "https://neighbor-hood.herokuapp.com/user/create",
 }
Object {
"isError": true,
"isLoading": false,
"isSuccess": false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think my API is working and when I try it on postman I get a 404 message.

This explains that you have some backend error because even when you are trying from postman you get `error of 404` which is error from backend.